# Hide shipping message until product is added to cart in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I have this code which tells the customer how much is left to spend until shipping is free. But, it shows as soon as you visit a product page no matter if  the product is added to the cart or not.

I would like it to show (see the various hooks) only after a product is added to cart. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'free_shipping_cart_notice_zones' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'free_shipping_cart_notice_zones' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_order_total', 'free_shipping_cart_notice_zones' );

    function free_shipping_cart_notice_zones() {
        global $woocommerce;
if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() != 0 ) {

        $default_zone = new WC_Shipping_Zone(0);
        $default_methods = $default_zone->get_shipping_methods();
        foreach( $default_methods as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $value->id === "free_shipping" ) {
              if ( $value->min_amount > 0 ) $min_amounts[] = $value->min_amount;
            } 
        }

        $delivery_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();
        foreach ( $delivery_zones as $key => $delivery_zone ) {
            foreach ( $delivery_zone['shipping_methods'] as $key => $value ) {
                if ( $value->id === "free_shipping" ) {
                    if ( $value->min_amount > 0 ) $min_amounts[] = $value->min_amount;
                } 
            } 
        }

        if ( is_array($min_amounts) ) {
            $min_amount = min($min_amounts);
            $current = WC()->cart->subtotal;

            if ( $current < $min_amount ) {
                $shipping_text = esc_html__('You are ', 'woocommerce' ) . wc_price( $min_amount - $current ) . esc_html__(' away from FREE SHIPPING!', 'woocommerce' );
                echo '<p class="delivery-message">' . $shipping_text . '</p>';
            } 
        }  
    }
}
```

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just inside the hook to display message check if cart empty

```
  global $woocommerce;
  if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() != 0 ) {
     // other codes here
  }
```

Comment: that worked, but after a product is added, the message goes away even though the free shipping amount is not reached, so using that solution won't work I'm afraid.

Comment: You are checking if cart is empty and at the same time you are checking for shipping amount. So it will work. Can you update the code in your question so that i can check ? @WooDevil

Comment: not sure if that is correct, but have a look now please.

Comment: @WooDevil Sry my answer had a mistake. You have to check `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() != 0`. Really sorry. I haven't seen the error in my answer. Sorry for your time

Comment: @WooDevil The code executed only when cart was empty. That made the issue. The code had to  work only if cart is not empty

Comment: @WooDevil I have updated my answer. Please check it and let me know if it works

Comment: yes - now it works as intended. Thank you, very kind of you to offer your time and help.

Comment: With pleasure. Really sorry for wasting your time with an errro. Good day :)